# SonarQube code coverage does not work for Kotlin files which contains various classes

Tags: kotlin, sonarqube, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am facing an issue with SonarQube 8.9 and the latest jacoco-maven-plugin 0.8.7.

I have a Kotlin project which is scanned by SonarQube for code coverage, all of my test files are well considered for coverage except kotlin test files which contain multiple classes, in this case I have the following logs for each inner classes of the kotlin file test:
`[WARNING] Resource not found: com.[NameOfTheInnerClassTest] under the directory /opt/#### while reading test reports. Please, make sure your "sonar.junit.reportPaths" property is configured properly`

In fact it looks for the inner test class (which is inside a kotlin file with other inner classes) in surefire-reports but it does not find it because there is actually only the enclosing file containing this class (with a different name therefore)

Did you run into this problem and if so how did you get around it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you get to resolve this at some point ?

Comment: No, and I gave up because finally the class being tested by this "special" class is covered by other tests so it's not embarrassing in my case but the original problem remains.